# How to create shell script to handle commands like ls -l /somedir

Tags: shell-script, scripting

My script so far can handle the `ls` command and returns the files in the directory. Now i am trying to make it handle commands like `ls -l /tmp` . Any help?

My script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
clear

read -p "type a command:  " file
    read -r -a prog <<<"$file"
    IFS=: read -r -a paths <<<"$PATH"

        for val in "${prog[@]}" ; do 
        for path in "${paths[@]}"; do       

          [[ -x $path/$val ]] && "$path/$val"  "$@"         
        done
        done
```

Comment: I thing tha the problem is at `$@` .Is there any way to take the rest part (`-l /tmp`) of the` ls -l /tmp`

Comment: You want to split the user's input into an array? Because you could simply get the whole line and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
clear
IFS=: read -r -a paths <<<"$PATH"
read -p "type a command:  " cmd
read -d ' ' file <<<"$cmd"  #the first component of command
for path in "${paths[@]}"; do       
  [ -x "$path/$file" ] && eval "$path/$cmd"
done
```

This basically runs the inputted command for every possible PATH resolution.

Comment: Your script also handles corect commands with pipes . Am i right? @PSkocik

Comment: That is correct.